# Difference between NotAcceptableHttpException and BadRequestHttpException

Tags: php, rest, laravel, http

I'm trying to get some clear information regarding `NotAcceptableHttpException` and `BadRequestHttpException`, but nothing in clear words, could someone tell me what is the difference between `NotAcceptableHttpException` and `BadRequestHttpException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **NotAcceptableHttpException represents a "Not Acceptable" HTTP exception with status code 406**
>
> Use this exception when the client requests a Content-Type that your application cannot return. Note that, according to the HTTP 1.1 specification, you are not required to respond with this status code in this situation.

[source](http://symfony.com/search?q=NotAcceptableHttpException)

> **BadRequestHttpException represents a "Bad Request" HTTP exception with status code 400.**
>
> Use this exception to represent a generic client error. In many cases, there may be an HTTP exception that more precisely describes the error. In that case, consider using the more precise exception to provide the user with additional information.

[source](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-badrequesthttpexception.html)

Answer (score 2):

See the [list of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error).  The server can return whatever error code it wants, but generally a 406 Not Acceptable means that your request asked for data in a form that the server cannot generate while 400 Bad Request means some other (less-specific) problem with the request.